# Use graphic representation to determine the zeroes of the function

Tags: numerical-methods

I want to solve the following question: Use graphic representation to determine the zeroes of the function to one correct decimal $f(x)=(x+1)e^{x-1}-1$.

This is a problem from the course book Numerical Methods, but since the book only has a answer and not a solution, I would appreciate help in understanding how to solve it.

**My thoughts**: Since it is to be solved graphically, I thought I would make a table of some values of the function f(x) and see how f(x) change with different values of x. For example for $1-x-e^{-2x}$ I tried with x on the range [0,1] since 1 is a solution for $1-x$ and 0 is a solution for $1-x-e^{-2x}$, but I do not know how to find these ranges for $f(x)=(x+1)e^{x-1}-1$ that I have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote "Since it is to be solved graphically, I thought I would make a table."  Huh?  You demand "graphically" but then proceed NON-graphically?!

"Graphically" means, well, *graphically*:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh, I apologize if I was unclear. I understood the question as meaning that I would compile the graph for the function myself, ie that I was not allowed to use tools such as a graphing calculator. My mistake.